# Python pd.read_sql where cause parameters

Tags: python, pandas

**Use case:**
We have nested queries and our tables have 10 to 20 million rows. Here our intention is to reduce the query CPU time by smart filter

***I like to filter my columns in pd.read_sql by other data frame column name. Is that possible?***

Step 1: df1 data frame age1 and age3 are my future filter columns for pd.read_sql

```
raw_data1 = {'age1': [23,45,21],'age2': [10,20,50], 'age3':['forty','fortyone','fortyfour']}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1, columns = ['age1','age2','age3'])
    df1
```

Step2: I like take age1 from above df1 dataframe want to use in below pd.read_sql like below to get item1 dataframe

```
item1 = pd.read_sql("""
SELECT * from [dbo].[ITEM]
where item_age1 = df1.age1
""", conn)
```

Step3: I like to take age3 from above df1 dataframe want to use in below pd.read_sql like below to get item2 dataframe

```
item2 = pd.read_sql("""
SELECT * from [dbo].[ITEM]
where item_age3 = df1.age3
""", conn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a parameterized query:

```
item2 = pd.read_sql("""
SELECT * from [dbo].[ITEM]
where item_age3 IN ({})
""".format(','.join('?'*len(df1.age3))), conn, 
params=list(df1.age3))
```

depending on the database backend this syntax may use `'%s'` or `%(name)s` instead of `'?'`. See PEP249 `paramstyle` for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I am using MS-SQL server and given logic did work perfectly.